# how to validate the uniqueness of a record based on the user who posted it in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model for User, Link and Report. A user can create multiple links. And a user can report multiple links. But a user cannot report one link multiple times.

Here's my models:-

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
  has_many :links

class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reports

class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :link
  belongs_to :user
```

I've tried the following without luck.

```
has_one :user, through: :link
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
validates_uniqueness_of :link_id, scope: :user_id
```

I thought it would be quite simple. but seems not. Help would be appreciated.

I'm on Rails 5.

Comment: Do you mean you want your user to have uniq link_id or body inside Link model?

Comment: Nevermind. It works, just my spec failed. So I thought it didn't work. What worked was `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :link_id`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It works, just my test spec failed. So I thought it didn't work. What worked was `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :link_id`